# Dynamics of the Kalman Filter and testing efficacy of the filter

Tags: time-series, bayesian, estimation, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I have a few questions:

1. What statistical tests should we run to test the performance of the Kalman Filter?
2. Should I expect the difference between the forecast estimates and the observations to converge to zero over time?
3. Should I expect the difference between the posterior estimate and the observations to converge to zero?
4. Bonus question which should be posted to stackoverflow: In R, using the DSE package, how do I call the posterior estimates? Is it by using state() function?

Comment: What do you mean by "performance"? Are you sure you want to use hypothesis testing to make sure you coded something correctly? Or are you using it to test something you could probably prove? And which posterior distribution are you talking about (states I'm guessing)?

Comment: @Taylor thanks for answering. By "performance" I mean that I would like to determine time to convergence of the prediction model, or at least to quantify improvement in predictions over time.  The posterior distribution I am talking about is the posterior estimate of the state, after getting an observation i.e. the updated estimate of the state after taking into account the observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I remember some specific results about convergence of the filtering covariance matrix (not mean) and convergence of the Kalman gain matrix. However, I think these are only true for specific models.

For example, in section 2.3 of [Bayesian Forecasting and Dynamic Models](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387947259), the authors show these types of convergence for the random walk plus noise model.

I also remember that these authors also deal with evaluating out-of-sample forecast performance by evaluating their forecast distributions at the out-of-sample data. High (log-)densities are good, while low ones are bad. This stuff is very much akin to Bayes Factors and prior prediction distributions. Under certain assumptions, I am sure you can invoke a limiting argument to justify convergence of these logged quantities to some entropy-based quantity.

Comment: thanks very much, this book you recommended is turning out to have everything I need